# Text box string not recognized as valid DateTime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, textbox

```
const double PERCENT = 0.25;


DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_StartT.Text);
DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_EndT.Text);
TimeSpan ts = t1.Subtract(t2);
```

I cant seem to get this to parse into a DateTime

```
double tsMin = Convert.ToDouble(ts);
double tsMinTot = ts.TotalMinutes;
short tsMinPercent = (short)(((double)tsMinTot) * PERCENT);
double tsAndPercentTot = tsMinPercent + tsMinTot;
```

My goal here was to find a timediff, find what 25% of that timediff is and add it to the timediff.

```
DateTime newTimeMinTot = Convert.ToDateTime(tsAndPercentTot);
int hours = newTimeMinTot.Hour;
int minutes = newTimeMinTot.Minute;
```

An attempt to get a calculated new Datetime

```
string newTimeStrg = string.Format("{0:d1}:{1:d2}", hours, minutes);
txtB_NewDelivT.Text = newTimeStrg;
```

Attempt to output new DateTime to TextBox.

Someone please explain. How can I make the user input in military time and make this work.

Comment: Which line you get an error exactly? What are the value of `txtB_StartT.Text` and `txtB_EndT.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Use the `DateTime.ParseExact` here is more on it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_StartT.Text);

Comment: the values of the both text boxes are input by the user, when clicking the button a new end time should be output into txtB_NewDelivT.Text . Im not exactly sure what my CurrenentCulture is or even what a CurrentCulture is :/.

Comment: You should validate your textbox for only accept the valid date values with the any format which is suitable to you and then use `ParseExact` to convert it to DateTime. Take a look here to how to get the current culture https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How? Do I validate the text box?

Comment: Is there a way to parse for time specifically as in just hh:mm format?

Comment: Along a none connected path, why are you casting to double after you have done Convert.ToDouble()?  This is redundant.

Comment: Hmm, that's how i thought it was typed out. But thank you now i know for future reference

Comment: Please show us what exactly the two textboxes contains before executing that code. I mean what have been typed by the user (or you being the user) inside those TextBoxes.

Comment: well the user should be able to input any valid time in 24 military time frame. For example i am using the times 0945 in txtB_StartT and 1445 in txtB_EndT

Comment: Are "0945" and "1445" the exact whole texts you typed inside the textboxes? no separators have been typed? and no date part is present? Anyway, if the text is not resembling a standard or system format, you should specifiy it in some way. Please also consider the usage of DateTime.Parse, DateTime.ParseExact, DateTime.TryParse, DateTime.TryParseExact overloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
const double PERCENT = 0.25;

DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_StartT.Text);
DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_EndT.Text);
TimeSpan ts = t1.Subtract(t2);

long tsMinPercent = ts.Ticks + (long)(ts.Ticks * PERCENT);

var tsAndPercentTot = TimeSpan.FromTicks(tsMinPercent);

string newTimeStrg = string.Format("{0:d1}:{1:d2}", tsAndPercentTot.Hours, tsAndPercentTot.Minutes);
txtB_NewDelivT.Text = newTimeStrg;
```

Here I am using [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) to calculate percentage of time of difference and [`TimeSpan.FromTicks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromticks(v=vs.110).aspx) to find `DateTime` again from calculated percentage DateTime.

Instead using `TextBox` you can use `TimePicker`.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same  An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. on the first datetime

Comment: Show me `txtB_StartT.Text` and `txtB_EndT.Text`, by using debugging.

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Copy exception detail?

Comment: No, put break point at line `DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_StartT.Text);` and find value of Text box for which user enter value, you can even use `TimePicker` to solve your problem

Comment: not sure how to do that but i have found this point to be the culprit ............Debugger:Exception Intercepted: button1_Click, Form1.cs line 26
An exception was intercepted and the call stack unwound to the point before the call from user code where the exception occurred.  "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" is selected in the debugger options.
Time: 2/9/2015 2:41:27 AM
Thread:<No Name>[20816]

Comment: then this .........................Exception:Thrown: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." (System.FormatException)
A System.FormatException was thrown: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
Time: 2/9/2015 2:42:00 AM
Thread:<No Name>[20816]

Comment: and this..................Debugger:Stopped at Exception: Parse
An exception was caught by the debugger, and user settings indicate that a break should occur.
Time: 2/9/2015 2:42:00 AM
Thread:<No Name>[20816]

Comment: Fine, looks like problem is `AM` `PM` part in `dateTime`. As per your question you might required only `Time` part from `DateTime`, right? So why not use `TimePicker` control to take only Time input?, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170684/Time-Picker

Comment: How do i use the time picker control? Sorry still having an issue

Comment: @soto. Hi. You are reporting the date/time of execution that the debugger show you in order to understand where and when the exception occurred. Your error dump is missing the most important part: the values that the TextBoxes contain and thus you are passing to Convert.ToDateTime, that is the string argument that causes the exceptions to occur.

Answer (score 0):

to force your date/datetime format

```
DateTime mydate =   DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: yes it will work , and use HH:mm if you want to use the 24 format, if you use hh:mm , then the result datetime will be current date+yourtime

Comment: yeah i just tried that and still getting.                                                                                                   An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @Soto You must be missing something else... `DateTime.ParseExact("10:43", "HH:mm", null)` worked just fine for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MlFTQm

Comment: Hmm im sure you're correct. I must have been doing something wrong, but i did end up with a different solution to the problem. I posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment where you write that the input values are "0945" and "1445", I suggest you to replace your TextBox controls with DateTimePicker controls.

Just to have them display values as you are doing right now, you'll have to set some properties as I show you here.

```
picker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
picker.CustomFormat = "HHmm";
picker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

later, the picker.Value will return a whole date with time, where minutes and seconds will resemble the input values.

You can obvously set the properties' values from the designer.

Regards,
Daniele.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your form, I'll leave out the UI interaction. Here's how you can parse an input stream. I've show how to parse a hh:mm format, as well as a hhmm format:

```
var start = TimeSpan.ParseExact("10:00", "hh\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var finish = TimeSpan.ParseExact("1100", "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Once you have the start and finish, all we have to do is the math. We'll create a new TimeSpan from the ticks (the smallest unit of measurement on a TimeSpan) multiplied by our percentage (0.25). Then we just add the adjustment to our start time and we're done! You can then assign that into where ever you need the output.

```
var diff = finish - start;
var adjustment = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)(diff.Ticks * 0.25));
var adjustedStart = start + adjustment;
```

You can run the code out at [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wCfuEP). I've included output there so you can see the intermediate results along the way.

Answer (score -1):

Ok well i took a different approach and it worked out fairly easy.
I'm not sure if I'm allowed to answer my own question but i figure it 
will help someone with the same issue i had.

```
    // Set Constant values.
    const double PERCENT = .25;
    const int HUN_PART = 100, SIXTY = 60, one = 1;

                // Parse start time textbox value as int 
                // Calculate start time hours and minutes                    
                int sT = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                int sH = sT / HUN_PART;
                int sM = sT % HUN_PART;

                        // Calculate total start time in minutes
                        int sH_M = sH * SIXTY;
                        int sTotM = sH_M + sM;

                // Parse end time textbox value as int
                // Calculate end time hours and minutes
                int eT = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                int eH = eT / HUN_PART;
                int eM = eT % HUN_PART;

                        // Calculate total end time in minutes
                        int eH_M = eH * SIXTY;
                        int eTotM = eH_M + eM;

                // Calculate time difference in minutea
                // Calculate percent of time difference
                double dT_M = Convert.ToInt32(eTotM - sTotM);
                int perc = Convert.ToInt32(dT_M * PERCENT);

                        // Calculate new arrival time in total min then in hours
                        double newD_M = perc + eTotM;
                        double newD_H = newD_M / SIXTY;

                // Calculate new arrivaltime in remaining minutes
                double nD_H_Convert = Math.Truncate(newD_H);
                int nD_H = Convert.ToInt32(nD_H_Convert);
                int nD_Hours = nD_H * HUN_PART;
                double nD_Min = nD_H * SIXTY;
                int nD_M = Convert.ToInt32(newD_M - nD_Min);
                int newDeliveryTime = (nD_H * HUN_PART) + nD_M;

                // Put values for new arive time hours and minutes in appropriate string format
                string newTime = string.Format("{0:d4}", newDeliveryTime);

                // Output arrival time string in textbox
                textBox3.Text = newTime;
```

I was apparently trying to do more than was actually required, so by using a few simple calculations the issue was resolved.

Thank you for the help everyone.

Comment: Did you consider using the TimeSpan class? That sounds more suitable for your needs than a DateTime. This seems like waaaay too much code for solving the problem at hand. There should be an easier way.

Comment: I attempted using it but it didn't seem to work out for me. I don't exactly understand all the ins and outs of C#, so im sure a made some mistake along the way. But my solution worked out fine for the purposes of my CS class.

Comment: /Aside: You should use `camelCase` not `under_scores` for local scope variable names in .NET. Also, your variable names should be TED (Terse, Expressive, and Does-One-Thing). I have no idea what `nD_H_Convert` means and neither will the person who has to maintain this code. The number of comments signals that the logic is complicated enough that it probably merit being split apart into separate methods. Think about how you can write it in a clearer way that doesn't require comments to explain what is happening. Comments should explain "Why", not "What".

Comment: @JeffBridgman though for the sake of most CS classes comments tend to be completely unimportant ;)